# Eureka service can not be found when running in Docker Container

Tags: spring, docker, dockerfile, microservices, netflix-eureka

So I have a very simple setup of a Eureka server and one service. When running locally with tomcat everything works perfect. However, when I run these locally in docker containers.. the service registers to the eureka server but whenever I make the http calls via FeignClient it says there is no load balance for the service (Cant find service). It acts as if the service can find the eureka server but the server can not find the service. And once again, only broken when runnind in docker containers.

My Eureka server

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
server.port=8761
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
```

My Service

```
spring.application.name=users-service
server.port=8081
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://**EurekaServerIp**:8761\eureka
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by making sure my Eureka server, Services and Zuul gateway were running on the same (Overlay) docker network. However, I now need to find a way to only make the zuul gateway accessible from outside the network, and protect all the services.

EDIT: I found a very easy way to expose gateways and hide services with docker --link, here is a good article https://exampledriven.wordpress.com/2016/06/24/spring-boot-docker-example/